# missing directories don't trigger Error Document Handling htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Basically, I've got the following .htaccess file:

```
Options -Indexes

ErrorDocument 400 /index.php?error=400
ErrorDocument 401 /index.php?error=400
ErrorDocument 403 /index.php?error=400
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=400
ErrorDocument 500 /index.php?error=400

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Enable sites without extentions
options +MultiViews

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks

  # Adaptive-Images -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # Add any directories you wish to omit from the Adaptive-Images process on a new line, as follows:
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ignore-this-directory
  # RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !and-ignore-this-directory-too

  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !img

  # don't apply the AI behaviour to images inside AI's cache folder:
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ai-cache

  # Send any GIF, JPG, or PNG request that IS NOT stored inside one of the above directories
  # to adaptive-images.php so we can select appropriately sized versions

 # RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|png)$ adaptive-images.php

  # END Adaptive-Images -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  # SEO Friendly Redirect Rules -----------------------------------------------------------------------


    RewriteRule ^(admin)/?$ admin/ [L,NC]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?title=$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9_]+)/([A-Za-z0-9_]*)/?$ index.php?title=$1&ch=$2 [L]
    RewriteRule /$ index.php [END]
```

As of right now, the rules and conditions all work great except for one thing. If I navigate to say: "example.com/nonexistingfolder" , it is using this rule to process:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?title=$1 [L]
```

Which brings up a php error because the argument passed is invalid. Which is to be expected, because it doesn't exist.  But if I no navigate to: "example.com/nonexistingfolder/index.php" , I'm correctly greeted with my 404 page defined at the top. (don't worry about the slashes, in the original these are permalinks)

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=400
```

I don't know too much outside of what I've learned today about .htaccess and mod_rewrite. Is there some other way I should be going about this? Or am I missing other statements?

I've tried adding the following lines to my .htaccess with no progress:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
```

Either these don't help in my case (and I thought the second would for sure), or I am still doing something wrong.

I expected the code to be rather straightforward, however this has left me scratching my head for a couple of hours. Thanks for taking the time to read and ponder this with me! Have a good one.

EDIT: I added these three lines of code:

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule .? /index.php?error=400 [L]
```

Which works when I navigate to something that doesn't exist. Yet, it interrupts the other RewriteRule I have set: `RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ /index.php?title=$1 [L]`

So now I am for sure at a loss at what to do.

To further exemplify:

Say I navigate to "website.com/nonexistingfolder". Which now because I added the three lines above, shows the 404 page correctly. However, because of the single RewriteRule above, if I navigate to: "website.com/indexquery" it will also show the 404. How can I tell my .htaccess to differentiate between the two?

Comment: _“How can I tell my .htaccess to differentiate between the two?”_ - you can’t. `/indexquery` does not physically exist any more than `/nonexistingfolder` - so you can not base the decision on that, at that point. Your index.php is the part of your setup that is looking up the matching content based on what you pass for the title parameter  - so your index.php should also handle the 404 case, when it can’t find any matching content. In your .htaccess, that info is not available.

Comment: Ah I see , okay. I can implement something along these lines. Thanks for your help.